# setenv usage in csh shell - unexpected results

Tags: scripting, csh, setenv

I have a big csh file, where I use set env command, to override the variable value.

```
setenv THE_VAR TV_012_3_45
echo the number: $THE_VAR
```

However, in the output file, it gets

`echo the number: TV_678_9_10`

I donot understand what might be the reason. There are a lot of scripts that might get called within this, csh file, but I just wanted to override the existing variable. No error or lead was found. Any ideas on what can be done.

I am expecting, like
`echo the number: TV_012_3_45`

Comment: As I expected, I can't reproduce this. Here's my test run (wrapped by the comment non-formatter) ... `./testR.csh
the number: TV_012_3_45` . I'm betting you don't really have a var name `THE_VAR`, but of course that's not the problem. Does your *"big csh file"* contain any `source` cmds? If so, you need to figure out which version of the named "*source*" file is being used, and then `grep THE_VAR ./myBigCshFile.csh /path/to/srcdFile1 /path/to/srcdFile2 ... /path/to/srrcdFileN`.  ....

Comment: You can also get csh debug/trace activated by changing top line to `#!/bin/csh -vx` (Hmm, we always used `..csh -f`, don't remember why after 20+ yrs, but you might wnat to add that in a separate test).  The debug trace will show any loops in complete detail, then show each line that is going to be executed, still showing `$THE_VAR`, and then it will show that line with the env var expanded, .e. `echo the number: TV_012_3_45` and finally it will show the actual result of running that command : `the number: TV_012_3_45`

Comment: That output gets rather messy from a big script. I recommend making sure your terminal history is expanded to 1,000,000 lines or more. Then after script has finished, use the `select all` and paste into your favorite editor, and save as a file so you can clean up and search the file more easily. Good luck.

Comment: Not my best comments ever, but intended to help. Let me know how you are doing. Good luck.